# awk command to delimit the second column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, cut

I have a file with data in the below format

```
Item1|keys,books,helmet,handle,
Item2|Bike,
Item3
Item4|Tyre,brakes,headlight,clamps,rollergrip,
Item5|Nails,hammers,
```

I wanted the above data to be converted to the below format

```
Item1|keys
Item1|books
Item1|helmet
Item1|handle
Item2|Bike
Item3
Item4|Tyre
Item4|brakes
Item4|headlight
Item4|clamps
Item4|rollergrip
Item5|Nails
Item5|hammers
```

I was trying to achieve this by using cut command though that was working fine I wanted to know can this be achieved using awk command. Since if the input file size gets bigger then it should be cumbersome.

Comment: Any feedback on the proposed answers @ramp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/,$//' -e '/^[^|]*$/s/$/|/' file.in |
awk -F'[|,]' -vOFS='|' '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) { print $1, $i } }'
```

The `sed` does a bit of preprocessing of the input data. It removes the trailing commas at the end of each line (`-e 's/,$//'`), and if a line doesn't contain a pipe symbol, it adds one to the end (`-e '/^[^|]*$/s/$/|/'`).

The example data is transformed into the following by the `sed` filter:

```
Item1|keys,books,helmet,handle
Item2|Bike
Item3|
Item4|Tyre,brakes,headlight,clamps,rollergrip
Item5|Nails,hammers
```

The `awk` script takes this and interprets each line as a set of fields separated by either a pipe symbol or a comma (`-F'[|,]'`). For each input line, it will then repeatedly pair up the first field with each of the other fields and output them. Each pair of fields in the output are separated by a pipe symbol (`-vOFS='|'`).

The result is

```
Item1|keys
Item1|books
Item1|helmet
Item1|handle
Item2|Bike
Item3|
Item4|Tyre
Item4|brakes
Item4|headlight
Item4|clamps
Item4|rollergrip
Item5|Nails
Item5|hammers
```

Comment: @steeldriver Hmmm... What `awk` are you using? I've tested this with GNU `awk`, `mawk` and with BSD `awk`. The reason I added the `|` to the line with only one field with `sed` was to get an empty field. `NF` will be 2 for that line.

Comment: Doh sorry I missed the fact that you are filtering through `sed` first. Apologies.

Comment: @steeldriver No worries! Yes, just to simplify the `awk` script a bit...

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF>1 && $2~/[^,]+,[^,]*/{ 
           len=split($2,a,","); 
           for(i=1;i<=len;i++) { 
               if(a[i]!="") print $1,a[i] 
           } 
           next }1' OFS='|' file
```

The output:

```
Item1|keys
Item1|books
Item1|helmet
Item1|handle
Item2|Bike
Item3
Item4|Tyre
Item4|brakes
Item4|headlight
Item4|clamps
Item4|rollergrip
Item5|Nails
Item5|hammers
```

---

*Details*:

- `-F'|'` - field separator
- `NF>1 && $2~/[^,]+,[^,]*/` - considers at least 2 fields with comma-separated values within the 2nd field
- `len=split($2,a,",")` - split the 2nd field into array `a` by separator `,`. The `len` variable is assigned with array size(number of chunks)
- `for(i=1;i<=len;i++)`  iterating through the "*chunks*"
- `if(a[i]!="") print $1,a[i]` - print each related sequence except empty values

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` version

- set the field separator to `|` or `,`
- if the record has fewer than 2 fields, print it as-is
- else loop over all fields 2 to `NF-1` printing `$1` and `$i` (this skips the empty `$NF` caused by the trailing comma

i.e.

```
$ awk 'NF<2 ; {for (i=2;i<NF;i++) print $1,$i}' FS='[|,]' OFS='|' file
Item1|keys
Item1|books
Item1|helmet
Item1|handle
Item2|Bike
Item3
Item4|Tyre
Item4|brakes
Item4|headlight
Item4|clamps
Item4|rollergrip
Item5|Nails
Item5|hammers
```